# Displaying array total in textfield from pickerview

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

[This is a screen shot of the app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9acf.png) I'm trying to get the sum of the array to display in the textfield after adding last picker view selection by pressing next button.

This is a golf score app I've been working on but I'm new to swift. It may be a mess, but I've been trying several different configurations.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    var ballArray : Array = ["ball1", "ball2", "ball3", "ball4", "ball5", "ball6", "ball7", "ball8", "ball9", "ball10", "ball11", "ball12", "ball13", "ball14", "ball15", "ball16", "ball17", "ball18","score"]
    var firstIndex : Int = 0


    var parScores = [Int]()
    var player1Scores = [Int]()
    var player2Scores = [Int]()
    var player3Scores = [Int]()
    var player4Scores = [Int]()
    var player5Scores = [Int]()
    var player6Scores = [Int]()

    var par : Int = 0
    var p1 : Int = 0
    var p2 : Int = 0
    var p3 : Int = 0
    var p4 : Int = 0
    var p5 : Int = 0
    var p6 : Int = 0


    var parArray  = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    var player1Array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    var player2Array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    var player3Array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    var player4Array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    var player5Array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    var player6Array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

    let pars = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"]
    let player1 = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"]
    let player2 = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"]
    let player3 = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"]
    let player4 = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"]
    let player5 = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"]
    let player6 = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"]



    @IBOutlet weak var ball1: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var PickerPar: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Picker1: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Picker2: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Picker3: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Picker4: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Picker5: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Picker6: UIPickerView!


    //    let par = UIPickerView()
    //    let p1 = UIPickerView()
    //    let p2 = UIPickerView()
    //    let p3 = UIPickerView()
    //    let p4 = UIPickerView()
    //    let p5 = UIPickerView()
    //    let p6 = UIPickerView()
    //


    @IBOutlet weak var parScore: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var player1Score: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var player2Score: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var player3Score: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var player4Score: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var player5Score: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var player6Score: UITextField!




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    //        var parSum = parScores.reduce(0, +)
    //        var player1Sum = player1Scores.reduce(0, +)
    //        var player2Sum = player2Scores.reduce(0, +)
    //        var player3Sum = player3Scores.reduce(0, +)
    //        var player4Sum = player4Scores.reduce(0, +)
    //        var player5Sum = player5Scores.reduce(0, +)
    //        var player6Sum = player6Scores.reduce(0, +)

        PickerPar.delegate = self
        PickerPar.dataSource = self
        PickerPar.tag = 0

        Picker1.delegate = self
        Picker1.dataSource = self
        Picker1.tag = 1

        Picker2.delegate = self
        Picker2.dataSource = self
        Picker2.tag = 2

        Picker3.delegate = self
        Picker3.dataSource = self
        Picker3.tag = 3

        Picker4.delegate = self
        Picker4.dataSource = self
        Picker4.tag = 4

        Picker5.delegate = self
        Picker5.dataSource = self
        Picker5.tag = 5

        Picker6.delegate = self
        Picker6.dataSource = self
        Picker6.tag = 6

        parScore.tag = 0
        player1Score.tag = 1
        player2Score.tag = 2
        player3Score.tag = 3
        player4Score.tag = 4
        player5Score.tag = 5
        player6Score.tag = 6



        }
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if PickerPar.tag == 0 {
            return parArray.count
        } else if Picker1.tag == 1 {
            return player1Array.count
        } else if Picker2.tag == 2 {
            return player2Array.count
        } else if Picker3.tag == 3 {
            return player3Array.count
        } else if Picker4.tag == 4 {
            return player4Array.count
        } else if Picker5.tag == 5 {
            return player5Array.count
        } else if Picker6.tag == 6 {
            return player6Array.count
        }
        return 1

    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if PickerPar.tag == 0 {
            return pars[row]
        } else if Picker1.tag == 1 {
            return player1[row]
        } else if Picker2.tag == 2 {
            return player2[row]
        } else if Picker3.tag == 3 {
            return player3[row]
        } else if Picker4.tag == 4 {
            return player4[row]
        } else if Picker5.tag == 5 {
            return player5[row]
        } else if Picker6.tag == 6 {
            return player6[row]
        }

        return ""

    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if PickerPar.tag == 0 {
            self.parScore.text = pars[row]
        } else if Picker1.tag == 1 {
            self.player1Score.text = player1[row]
        } else if Picker2.tag == 2 {
            self.player2Score.text = player2[row]
        } else if Picker3.tag == 3 {
            self.player3Score.text = player3[row]
        } else if Picker4.tag == 4 {
            self.player4Score.text = player4[row]
        } else if Picker5.tag == 5 {
            self.player5Score.text = player5[row]
        } else if Picker6.tag == 6 {
            self.player6Score.text = player6[row]
        }

     }





    @IBAction func nextButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {





         if firstIndex < 18 {
             updateBallImages()
             updatePar()
             updateP1()
             updateP2()
             updateP3()
             updateP4()
             updateP5()
             updateP6()
         }
            else if firstIndex == 18{
            repeatProg()
            }
            }
    func updateBallImages(){

        firstIndex = Int((firstIndex+1))
        ball1.image = UIImage(named: ballArray[firstIndex])
    }
    func repeatProg(){

        firstIndex = Int((firstIndex+1))
        ball1.image = UIImage(named: ballArray[firstIndex])
    }
    func updatePar(){

        par = Int(par)
        parScore.text = String(parArray[par])
    }
    func updateP1(){
        p1 = Int(p1)
        player1Score.text = String(player1Array[p1])
    }
    func updateP2(){
        p2 = Int(p2)
        player2Score.text = String(player2Array[p2])

    }
    func updateP3(){
       p3 = Int(p3)
        player3Score.text = String(player3Array[p3])
    }
    func updateP4(){
        p4 = Int(p4)
        player4Score.text = String(player4Array[p4])
    }
    func updateP5(){
        p5 = Int(p5)
        player5Score.text = String(player5Array[p5])
    }
    func updateP6(){
       print(p6 = player6Scores.reduce(0, +))
        player6Score.text = String(player6Array[p6])
    }
}
```

The output I'm looking for will be shown for every pickerview in its assigned textfield. A sum accumulated from each button press.

Comment: unclear what you're asking

Comment: A score is chosen in each of 7 uipickerviews. When the UIButton is pressed, the score goes to the UITextField. Then another score is chosen in the UIPickerview. Press the button again and it adds that score to the total in the UITextfield. It will accumulate the score until the last hole (18th hole). Once I get this fixed, I will make a score card for the next page past 18.